# Regex to match sub string of a string

Tags: regex, angular

I need to construct a regular expression to match a given value to the brand field of my product array. For instance, given the parameter "am", an array of the following products would be returned: [Amana, Mama, etc]. How do I complete this function?

```
public searchProduct(term) {
   this.products.forEach(product => {
     if (product.brand.match(`${term}`)) {
       console.log('mtch found', product.brand)
     }

   });
   return of(this.products)
 }
```

Comment: find a regex tester with google and play around with test data and test regexes. most have documentation to help you write it.

Comment: Take a look at the [array filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have some special reasons to use regex, you can use `filter` and `includes` to return only items of your array containing your substring

```
public searchProduct(term) {
  return this.products.filter(x => x.brand.includes(term))
 }
```